# how to make circle to rectangle using javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

hi guys i'm starting to learn about canvas using javascript.
I have a question if there is any way to transform a circle to rectangle smoothly

something like this?? [image: 1]

Comment: no, canvas is just a painting system

Comment: Take a look at [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D), this would require little knowledge about [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG), especially the [`<path>`-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) and its [`d`-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d). You'd need to create the animation by using a timing-method, which you'd have to program yourself. E.g. [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) can be used.

Answer (score 2):

### Morphing shapes.

The easiest method is to create two reference shapes and tween between the two shapes.

As a rectangle and circle are created from lines, and arcs respectively it is not easy to create a square from circles. However you can create a circle from many small lines.

The example/demo snippet implements the following methods

### Tweening

Tweening is a method of interpolating between two states.

The amount that we shift between the two states is defined by a unit value (a value from 0 to 1).

If the value is 0 the we are in the start state, if 1 then in the end state, values between are a fraction between the two end states.

The function that does the Tweening is called `tweenPaths(ctx, pathA, pathB, pod)`

### Create the shapes

To get the correct look the points on start shape must be as close as possible to the points on the end shape. You also need to consider things like corners making sure you have a point on both shapes that will define a corner on one of the shapes.

#### The circle

The function `circle(r, points)` creates a circle out of a set of line segments. `r` is radius and `points` is the number of points

#### The square

The function `square(size, points)` starts by calculating a point on the circle and then pushes that point out from the center to where it would be on the square.

`size` is the width and height and `points` is the number of points

#### Points, Corners, position

**Note** that both circle and square MUST have the same number of points. To get the corners of the square the number of points needs to be divisible by 4

**Note** both shapes are centered on coordinate 0, 0. To draw at a specific point the 2D context transform sets the center (last two values).

`ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, ctx.canvas.width * 0.5, ctx.canvas.height * 0.5);`

In this case that is the center of the canvas.

### Example

The code below tweens between a circle and square.

The function `eCurve` eases in and out the tweening value.

To animate the process the example uses `requestAnimationFrame` to control the timing and rendering of the animation

```js
function circle(r, points)  {
    var i = 0;
    const path = [];
    while (i < points) {
       const a = (i++ / points) * Math.PI * 2;
       path.push({x: Math.cos(a) * r, y: Math.sin(a) * r});
    }
    return path;
}

function square(size, points)  {
    var i = 0;
    const path = [];
    while (i < points) {
       const a = (i++ / points) * Math.PI * 2;
       const x = Math.cos(a), y = Math.sin(a);
       const l =  Math.abs(x) - Math.abs(y) > 0 ?
            (size * 0.5) / x * Math.sign(x) :
            (size * 0.5) / y * Math.sign(y);
       path.push({x: x * l, y: y * l})
    }
    return path;
}

function tweenPaths(ctx, pathA, pathB, pos) { // pos = 0 PathA, pos = 1 PathB
    var i = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    while (i < pathA.length) {
        const A = pathA[i];
        const B = pathB[i];
        const x = (B.x - A.x) * pos + A.x;
        const y = (B.y - A.y) * pos + A.y;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        i++;
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

const eCurve   = (v, p = 2, vp) =>  v < 0 ? 0 : v > 1 ? 1 : (vp = v ** p) / (vp + (1 - v) ** p);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const size = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height) * 0.4;
const cir = circle(size, 200);
const sqr = square(size * 2, 200);
var tween = 0;
var tweenDir = 0.01;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    tween += tweenDir;
    if (tweenDir < 0 && tween <= 0) {
        tweenDir = -tweenDir;
        tween = 0;
    } else if (tweenDir > 0 && tween >= 1) {
        tweenDir = -tweenDir;
        tween = 1;
    }
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, ctx.canvas.width * 0.5, ctx.canvas.height * 0.5);
    tweenPaths(ctx, cir, sqr, eCurve(tween));

    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Mr.Jo `circle()` creates an array of points, which are placed on evenly distributed radial lines, so that connecting the points results in a circle. `square()` does mostly the same, but with the addition of moving the individual points out by that much, that connecting them results in a square. This means, for every `x` in `square.length`, `square[x]` and `circle[x]` are both placed on the same radial line, just with a different offset from the center. `tweenPaths()` linearly interpolates between `pathA` and `pathB`, depending on `pos`, and immediately connects the resulting points.

Comment: @Mr.Jo `eCurve()` is just an ease-in-out function of `p` degree, defaulting to a quadratic function, with the result being in the range of 0 and 1. Correct me if I'm wrong, @Blindman67.

Comment: @OskarGrosser Yes spot on with the explanations (way better than the attempt in my answer).. However Mr Jo is referring to a different question contain code copied from an answer I wrote some years ago. :)

Comment: @Blindman67 If you are only interested in translating the context, `ctx.translate(x, y)` seems better suited than `ctx.setTransform(xScale, ySkew, xSkew, yScale, xTranslate, yTranslate)`. But I didn't know about `requestAnimationFrame()`, seems like a great way to reduce the amount of resources used when idle!

Comment: @OskarGrosser `ctx.translate` is converted to a matrix that multiplies the existing matrix  that then replaces current transform (12 multiplies 6 additions ).  `ctx.setTransform` is  a memory copy, all it does is replace existing transform, no hidden math calculation and quicker than any one call to `ctx.scale`, `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.translate` or `ctx.transform`. Quickest way to build a uniform matrix  `rx = Math.cos(r) * s; ry = Math.cos(r) * s; ctx.setTransform(rx, ry, -ry, rx, x, y)` .where  `r` is rotate, `s` scale,`x,y` origin

Answer (score 2):

The [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) allows the use of [path-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#paths) similar to [SVG's `<path>` `d`-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d).
If you have ever worked with SVG and CSS, then transforming a square to a circle seems like an easy task:

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://w3.org/2000/svg" fill="transparent" stroke="black">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="90" height="90" rx="0">
    <animate attributeName="rx" values="0;45;0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Here, we have a `<rect>`-element, whose `rx`-attribute is animated, from 0 to half its size. This results in a form, that looks like its transforming from a circle to a square.

As any form is made up from lines, curves and other geometric forms, it can be modelled using SVG's `<path>`-element and its `d`-attribute.

The Canvas API includes a class called [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D), which behaves exactly like SVG's `<path>`-element, just purpose-built for the canvas.
The Canvas API also includes path-functions to programmatically define the path to draw/fill.

Either `Path2D` or the path-functions may be used to achieve a transforming square-to-circle form.

## Example

As we are going to implement it using JavaScript, we can define our own custom animation-curve, here in `calcMutliplier()`.

The path to draw is defined in `render()`.

The animation is depending on how much time has passed. The objects are informed of passed time by calling `update()` with `dt` as its argument, containing the passed time in milliseconds.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class SquareCircleForm {
  x;
  y;
  size;
  cycleLength;
  progress = 0;
  
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, size = 0, cycleLength = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.cycleLength = cycleLength;
  }
  
  calcMultiplier() {
    return Math.abs((this.progress / this.cycleLength) * 2 - 1);
  }
  
  update(dt) {
    this.progress = (this.progress + dt) % this.cycleLength;
  }
  
  render(ctx) {
    const mult = this.calcMultiplier();
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, -this.size / 2); // Start point
    ctx.lineTo(this.size / 2 * mult, -this.size / 2); // Top edge - right half
    ctx.arcTo( // Top-right corner
      this.size / 2, -this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2, this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2 * (1 - mult)
    );
    ctx.lineTo(this.size / 2, this.size / 2 * mult); // Right edge
    ctx.arcTo( // Bottom-right corner
      this.size / 2, this.size / 2,
      -this.size / 2, this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2 * (1 - mult)
    );
    ctx.lineTo(-this.size / 2 * mult, this.size / 2); // Bottom edge
    ctx.arcTo( // Bottom-left corner
      -this.size / 2, this.size / 2,
      -this.size / 2, -this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2 * (1 - mult)
    );
    ctx.lineTo(-this.size / 2, -this.size / 2 * mult); // Left edge
    ctx.arcTo( // Top-left corner
      -this.size / 2, -this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2, -this.size / 2,
      this.size / 2 * (1 - mult)
    );
    // Top edge - left half not needed; `ctx.closePath()` connects start with end
    ctx.closePath();
    
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
class SquareCircleForm2 extends SquareCircleForm {
  constructor(x, y, size, cycleLength) {
    super(x, y, size, cycleLength);
    
    this.progress = this.cycleLength / 4;
  }
  
  calcMultiplier() {
    return Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * this.progress / this.cycleLength) / 2 + 0.5;
  }
}

const forms = []
// Using linear transformation
forms.push(new SquareCircleForm(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 2, 100, 2000));
// Using sine-wave transformation
forms.push(new SquareCircleForm2(canvas.width * 3 / 4, canvas.height / 2, 100, 2000));

const framesPerSecond = 30;

let start = Date.now();
setInterval(() => {
  const dt = Date.now() - start;
  
  // Reset canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // Update and draw forms
  forms.forEach(f => f.update(dt));
  forms.forEach(f => f.render(ctx));
  
  start = Date.now();
}, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Here, the left form animates linearly, and the right by sine-wave.

## End note

This answer is posted to offer another way of implementing your desired result.
However, I think [Blindman67's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110545/13561410) is, for most cases, better suited.

His example animates differently from mine, which is due to him positioning the square-points on the radial lines.

To achieve the same effect as in my example, you would have to create forms of `n` points, with `n` being divisible by 12. Then, you would have to place `n / 4` points in each of the corners, in the same direction in which you placed the circle-points, meaning clock- or counter-clockwise.
Then, it would be a simple matter of just using his `tweenPaths()` function.